# Shortcut Automatically Assign Result of An Expression into an Explicit Typed Named Variable [Visual Studio]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

Is there a shortcut to assign the result of an expression into a named variable?

I often write the expression first because I am not sure the data type returned.

Let's say:

```
Add(0.5, 1.5); // Luckily Intellisense tooltips tell me it returns double of 2.0
```

So, have to write this manually: `double result = <expression>` into:

```
double variable1 = Add(0.5, 1.5);
```

Since this happen almost all the time. Is there a shortcut/helpers to assign the result as variable?

(Code is written in C#)

Comment: You could write `var a = Add(0.5, 1.5)` and let VS determine the data type. See reference here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: I prefer **type** to be explicit, unless it is anonymous type or too long too write. More importantly it is for readability. So I avoid `var` for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've created the command [Create a typed variable from the current method invocation](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#CreateTypedVariable) for Visual Commander. It uses Roslyn and the main code is:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.SnapshotPoint caretPosition = textView.Caret.Position.BufferPosition;
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document document = caretPosition.Snapshot.GetOpenDocumentInCurrentContextWithChanges();
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpressionNode = 
    document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.FindToken(caretPosition).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf().
        OfType<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.InvocationExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
if (invocationExpressionNode != null)
{
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SemanticModel semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocationExpressionNode).Symbol as 
        Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.IMethodSymbol;
    textView.TextBuffer.Insert(invocationExpressionNode.SpanStart, methodSymbol.ReturnType.ToString() + " v = ");
}
```